# Visual Studio 2015 Release build uses wrong path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that has two versions in two spearate folders.

```
D:\OldProject\
D:\NewProject\
```

The OldProject is considered outdated, the new one is what I try to build.
When I try to build that project, I get build errors:

> Metadata file 'D:\OldProject\bin\net40\Release\Caliburn.Micro.dll'
>   could not be found

I checked the output path for the projects in NewProject, they refer to the `NewProject` path.

I checked the Project folder for the projects, they look like this:

```
D:\NewProject\Caliburn Micro\Caliburn.Micro\
```

Its output path is this:

```
..\..\bin\net40\Release\
```

The dlls are compiled to this path: `D:\NewProject\bin\net40\Release\`

What is wrong with the paths? Where should I set the proper path?

Comment: The Caliburn.Micro.dll you mentioned, is that added as a reference in your project? You can see it in the Solotuion Explorer under References. In the properties of that reference you can see the path of the dll. Is that pointing to the right folder?

Comment: It has this path in Reference Properties: `D:\NewProject\bin\net40\Release\Caliburn.Micro.dll`

Comment: So that's the right path. Hmm. I presume you also did a clean and rebuild?

Comment: When all else fails, delve into the .csproj files. Close VS, open them up the project files in eg Notepad and search for `OldProject` and replace all occurrences with `NewProject, then restart VS.

Comment: You can also edit the .csproj in VS, by right-clicking on your project, choosing Unload Project and then edit the .csproj file. After you are finished, save the file, right-click on your project and select Reload Project

Comment: Could you use any of our comments? Or did you solve the problem yourself?

Comment: None of the above suggestions worked. I ended up deleting the `NewFolder` folder and checked out the code to the `OldFolder` folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a suggestion that might work, not a surefire way, but for me that worked:

Delete `CMakeCaches.txt` and run `cmake ..` again